# CGI Script displayed as Plain Text in Apache2 (localhost)

Tags: html, perl, localhost, apache2, cgi

I currently have to do a web server in Apache2 that consists on a Login/Register web, and I have to call a CGI Script to validate the input data from the user. Well, when I call the script with the submit button, the CGI Script appears as Plain Text, and I don't know what else to do to fix it.

I have tried uncommenting CGI Modules in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf, setting a default directory for CGI Scripts, uncommenting the AddHandler for CGI and changing Options values in my localhost directory and in the CGI directory adding ExecCGI in them all. But it still does not work, it just appears as plain text.

P.S.: I followed this tutorial (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html) and also looked for the solution here in StackOverflow, but I got nothing working for me.

Edit: Also thank you for helping if you do :)

Comment: This is a question about Apache configuration, so it belongs on [sf].  Go back over the Apache docs on enabling CGI _very carefully_.  Clearly you have missed a step.

Comment: @JimGarrison I don't have that module "LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so", but I think I don't need it because I didn't build my Apache with shared module support. If not, I don't know what can it be.

Comment: Did you build in CGI support as a static module? Is that even possible?  Without CGI support _somewhere_ in the system it won't execute CGI programs.

Comment: Well I don't know, enabling that module is just for that kind of installation. Also I am using Apache2 in Mac OS High Sierra, so I don't have the same directories as the ones shown in the tutorial from Apache. Don't know if that supposes any problem...

Comment: Again, this question belongs on [sf].  Be sure to include all the information you provided in the comments as well.

Comment: Which operating system? Some Unix/Linux? The file is executable? But I agree, [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or even better [Super User](https://superuser.com/) is a better place for this question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the directory configuration, so I kept the default http.config file, that has a preset ScriptAlias for the /cgi-bin/ directory to the following directory:

> /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables

Then I enabled the CGI Module by uncommenting the line (removing the '#' before the line) in the httpd.conf file from apache2:

> LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so

Finally I saved the file, and then I restarted the Apache2 server using the command:

> sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart

Then I just pasted the .cgi script in the CGI-Executables directory, setting the permissions of the file as **chmod a+x**.

To run the script now you just have to access

> localhost/cgi-bin/script.cgi

Thank you for the help anyways!

Comment: Simply run sudo a2enmod cgi to enable on Apache 2.4 and restart apache2.